# How to reduce memory usage for android game?

Tags: andengine

I developed a game like "towerDefence" in android using AndEngine.
it's like alies are attacking on moument and we have to put weapons on different positions.
it contains around 20 levels.
bot now my problem is when i play 3 to 4 level continusly my game colsed automatically without giving any error message or any error log.

I tested in Micromax tab and Samsung tab 2 .

anyone have faced this problem and get rid of it then plz suggest any way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reuse your game objects by having an object pool. Analyze your program, and see where you're using `new` keyword. Try to reduce their count.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility chould be that, there are memory leakages in your code. Make sure you free all dynamically allocated memories as soon as it becomes useless(or wont be used in future).

You should try reading [this](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html) link for refrence.